# Ajax with JSON GET request undefined

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to get the front end to display the contents of my dynamo db table although it displays the information as undefined.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({

            type: 'GET',
            url:someURL,


            success: function(data){
                $('#incidentid').html('');

                data.forEach(function(IncidentNotesItem){
          $('#incidentid').append ('<p>'+ IncidentNotesItem.incidentid + '</p>');

                })
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure the function is working? Add an `error: function(response) { console.log(response.responsetext); }` function to your AJAX so we can see what the error is if one exists.

Comment: Is the AJAX request to the same domain?

Comment: I added that line and refreshed my webpage but the console is giving me a status 200 and yes, the AJAX request is to the same domain

Comment: But I still see undefined: undefined

undefined

undefined

undefined

undefined

Comment: Are you getting the response you are expecting? What's inside `data`?

Comment: data should get the incidentid from the dynamodb table which are 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: Check your browser devtools network tab and check that the ajax response contains what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! The issue was that I wasn't calling the column name properly. I did console.log(IncidentNotesItem) to see what is stored inside the IncidentNotesItem Function and saw on the console that it is called id instead of incidentid.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({

        type: 'GET',
        url:someURL,


        success: function(data){
            $('#incidentid').html('');

            data.forEach(function(IncidentNotesItem){
      $('#incidentid').append ('<p>'+ IncidentNotesItem.id + '</p>');

            })
        }
    });
});
```